# Who manufactures this bath tub faucet?

Tags: bathtub, tub

I have a bath tub faucet that leaks and needs valve replacement. No one seems to know what kind of faucet it is. I have sent a picture of it to the major suppliers and no one seems to know. Maybe someone out there can help. I have had plumbers here as well that do not know.

*Click on photo for full size*

[image: bath tub faucet]

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the exact brand. Remove the cartridge and go find a replacement at a plumbing store with a good selection.  If you can't find a replacement, you'll probably just have to replace the valve

Comment: The misery of discontinued brands - As @steven says, you can't tell till you remove the cartridge. The store will have a book with a listing of all these and diagrams you can match up to. The first time, I got lucky and bought what was probably the last one in the US. 10 years later, I ripped the wall out and replaced the plumbing and the valve with a well known brand since that's what it takes to replace these.

Answer (score 2):

This is a discontinued brand/manufacturer called Valley. My faucet handle broke and I saw your picture while I was researching for a replacement. I was able to get a replacement today from Biard & Crockett Plumbing Service Inc in Orange, CA.

Comment: Can you perhaps post a replacement part # so the OP can look for it at other vendors?

Comment: LASCO HC-170 Plastic Old Style Faucet Handle **Fits Valley Brand** –[Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/LASCO-HC-170-Plastic-Faucet-Handle/dp/B000FH9OHS/ref=pd_sim_60_5/181-8339402-6282845?ie=UTF8&dpID=519XI7ahxIL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&refRID=0DDTH24EWZ7SBYEK2PYN) - It has that same 'star' on it.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely an old-style Valley brand.  I have the same one and found a repair kit at Amazon.  I still need to make sure the Amazon kit includes the same cartridge as mine before ordering it.

The cover that needs to be removed (after removing the handle) can be loosened by spraying it with WD-40 and use regular big pliers to remove (turn left to loosen).

YouTube has a couple of videos showing how to replace a Valley cartridge.  They're not the best videos, but they might help.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a Moen or one of the Moen knockoffs. Moen units usually will have a name somewhere. This also might be a case where the handle was replaced with an off brand but the guts are genuine. As @ Steven has suggested remove the cartridge and bring it with you. Even if it is an older model the parts may span for many years and be available. Don't be discouraged if the big box stores don't carry what you need. Try a local hardware store. Most times they can order it if it isn't stocked.

Comment: If it's a Moen, she's in luck.

Comment: If it's a Moen valve (which I doubt), that's a replacement handle; wrong emblem.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than fuss over trying to get repair parts for an old mixer valve body, why not replace the entire unit?  You can upgrade to a good anti-scald, volume/temp control valve.  Any good plumber can easily remove the mixer and replace the unit,  You will need access to the back of the unit however.

The model of the mixer valve is almost always cast into the body.  Moen or Price Vista usually have a red/blue ying/yang logo somewhere. Has anyone removed the handle and wall trim to actually look at the valve body?

Comment: The hollow H and C font on the trim and the two upper mounting screws in a dish design kinda reminds me of an older Delta.

Comment: That escussion screams Delta at me. Same supplier/foundry I'd assume.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain that is a Valley Tub/Shower fixture.  I have the same one.  You can find replacement parts on-line. Just Google "Valley Tub/Shower Valve."

This link shows how to fix one of those.

http://plumbing.about.com/od/shower_and_tub/ss/Fix-A-Valley-Shower-Leak.htm

Answer (score -1):

that is the Moen 'tear drop'...I believe.